# Table with large data having outer page vertical scrollbar and inner horizontal table columns scrollbar with fixed column headers

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, angular-material, angular-material-table

[image]
[image]

How to achieve this through css or javascript for table which has outer page vertical scrollbar and inner horizontal table columns scrollbar with fixed column headers. When I scroll vertically table columns are not sticky.

I tried giving overflow-y hidden and overflow-x auto to mat table but it isn't working

```
.mat-table-container {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
  
.mat-table {
   width: 1000px;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
  
.mat-header-row {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the property 'Sticky' on true in your mat-header-row.

Example:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
```

Your can see this property [in the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sticky-rows-and-columns:%7E:text=link-,Sticky%20Rows%20and%20Columns,-By%20using%20position)

Comment: It doesnt remain sticky if we want to add vertical scrollbar at page level and horizontal scroll at table level